# Sharepoint 2010 on-prem opening documents as read only

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

As of today we started to experience that all documents in our SharePoint 2010 are being opened as **read-only**.

There have been no changes to the system. No updates were installed. No GPOs were pushed. The disks aren't full. SQL isn't full.

We can create new documents, we can edit and change site layouts, search works.
I am kind of at a loss here.

Looking at the event viewer i can see that every 5 minutes it throws a **Critical error ID 6398**. I have been in the Central Admin (monitoring) and i can see that in is an Indexing job that fails every 5 minutes.

P.S. i see that there are duplicates of this question on the site but none of them have an answer.

Comment: Is this happening with all document types or just certain ones like Excel?

Comment: Did your  SP Admin put the entire site collection in read-only mode?

Comment: Can you check this link :  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a0849e73-d347-4d12-8424-9d5bb6bfb004/all-office-files-from-sharepoint-are-opened-read-only?forum=w8itproappcompat

Comment: @DavidDrever all office documents

Comment: @SaMolPP no. i checked. there was no changes

Comment: the regedit thingy isnt working @SaMolPP

Comment: Seems that, the issue is with User Profile Serv.Appln. Can your reproduce the issue in your UAT/Staging environment and remove the User Profile Serv.Appln and recreate it in UAT/Staging environment and verify.If it works perform the same on your Prod. Note : this should be done very carefully, hence first execute the same on UAT/Staging  env.